# Trying to open .dot file with OO 4.1.0

Tags: windows-7

Cannot open .dot files with OO 4.1.0; OO crashes every time. What can I do? Is there a workaround? Please help!!! Should I re-install OO? I have even downloaded the OO Associator....that has NOT helped.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you try to open the file? Also, .dot files are created by Microsoft Word and they are *template files*. As those files are binary, why do you think you can open them in OpenOffice?

Comment: Does OpenOffice crash when you open different kind of documents?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting quotes around the file name in the dialogue box.  So if you want to open the file .me in your local home folder, type in

> "C:\Users\Darryl\.me"

INCLUDING quotes